# Unable to access localhost:7070 due to error in Apache Kylin

Tags: hbase, kylin, hadoop3

Good afternoon, I am having problems when trying to access  http://:7070. I installed the following programs: apache-hive-3.1.2-bin , kylin-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3 , kafka_2.12-2.5.0 , hadoop-3.3.0 , and hbase-2.3.4
I tend to think it has to do with some problem when connecting to HBase cause whenever I ran a list it gives me the following error:

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                         

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkServiceStarted(HMaster.java:2921)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.isMasterRunning(MasterRpcServices.java:1182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)
```

And when I search in log of HBase i get the following outcome:

```
$ less hbase-2.3.4/logs/hbase-cuquerella-master-tfg.log
2021-02-13 18:12:42,107 ERROR [master/tfg:16000:becomeActiveMaster] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master
java.io.IOException: cannot get log writer
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AsyncFSWALProvider.createAsyncWriter(AsyncFSWALProvider.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AsyncFSWAL.createWriterInstance(AsyncFSWAL.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:797)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.rollWriter(AbstractFSWAL.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.AbstractFSWAL.init(AbstractFSWAL.java:472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:158)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.AbstractFSWALProvider.getWAL(AbstractFSWALProvider.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.WALFactory.getWAL(WALFactory.java:288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.region.MasterRegion.createWAL(MasterRegion.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.region.MasterRegion.open(MasterRegion.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.region.MasterRegion.create(MasterRegion.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.region.MasterRegionFactory.create(MasterRegionFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:948)
```

I would greatly appreciate if anybody could shed some light upon the problem. I am sorry for any mistakes I have done while asking this question cause I am a real beginner at this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your HMaster is not running. What's your Hadoop platform? HDP or CDH?
Check HMaster's status in Ambari or Cloudera Manager, restart it if needed.